# Return, ¿No funciona en tarea programada?

Tags: php, laravel, shell-script

Tengo un controlador en Laravel, que es procesado cada cierto tiempo por una tarea programada desde el servidor.

Este controlador, hace un redirect:

```
  return redirect('/control_fich/'.$id_user.'/'.$date_utc);
```

A otro controlador que sigue procesando lo que se recoge de un Soap. (Este último dato es un poco irrelevante).

El tema es que cuando ejecuto este controlador manualmente, mediante la API, me lo procesa adecuadamente, pero cuando lo hace el ShellScript, automático, no me procesa el otro controlador.

Parece ser que return no se procesa mediante ShellScript, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para procesar el otro controlador?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta respuesta no está enfocada a ShellScript, pues no lo utilizo, va más enfocada al diseño de la aplicación:

En teoría es incorrecto que un controlador "llame" o redireccione a otro controlador, los controladores no deberían comunicarse entre ellos, para eso existen otras tantas capas o métodos como:

- Modelos
- Repositorios
- Servicios
- DI
- Interfaces
- Etcétera...

En resumen, deberías abstraer un poco más lo que intentas hacer para que los dos controladores lo puedan utilizar sin tener que llamarse el uno al otro.